# Command line input issues in Python

Tags: python, command-line

I am using this Tarjan algorithm in python to find circuits in a directed graph. I have tried all types of inputs but it's not working.

Here is [complete code](https://github.com/josch/cycles_tarjan) and following is the code that takes input.

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "usage: echo \"v1 v2\nv1 v3\n...\" | %s num_vertices"%(sys.argv[0])

A = [[] for a in range(int(sys.argv[1]))]

for edge in sys.stdin.readlines():
    v1,v2 = edge.split(' ', 1)
    A[int(v1)].append(int(v2));
```

I have given following inputs:

```
$ echo "3" "0 1 0 2 1 0 2 0 2 1" | python cycles.py
$ echo "3 0 1 0 2 1 0 2 0 2 1" | python cycles.py
$ echo "0 1\n0 2\n1 0\n1 3\n2 0\n3 0\n3 1\n3 2" | python cycles.py //as instructed.
```

but none of them is working. Can somebody help in figuring out the input format or is there some bug in the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Length of sys.argv**

The length of `sys.argv` is always going to include the name of the script itself. So for your script:

```
>> print len(sys.argv)
3
>> print sys.argv
['cycles.py', '3', '0 1 0 2 1 0 2 0 2 1']
```

**Error in your script**

You make a check that `sys.argv` must not be any other length than 2. When you pass in 2 arguments, sys.argv will have a length of 3.

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "usage: echo \"v1 v2\nv1 v3\n...\" | %s num_vertices"%(sys.argv[0])
```

Should be

```
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "usage: echo \"v1 v2\nv1 v3\n...\" | %s num_vertices"%(sys.argv[0])
```

**Invoking python scripts with arguments**

A much more readable way to invoke scripts would be to use this syntax:

```
python -i cycles.py "3" "0 1 0 2 1 0 2 0 2 1"
```